# You can play a land but you can't cast a land

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing a game with some friends and I played a [Mosswort Bridge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMosswort%20Bridge%5d) and whiffed, hitting all lands. But then I noticed that Mosswort Bridge lets you *play* a card without paying its mana cost so could I still put a land under the Mosswort Bridge and play it when the conditions are fulfilled?

Comment: Yes. To play a card is to cast it or to play it as a land.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In m10 they use this convention: you activate ability, cast spell and **play lands**

So from mtg rules

> 305. Lands
>
> 305.1. A player who has priority may play a land card from his or her hand during a main phase of his or her turn when the stack is empty.
> **Playing a land is a special action**; it doesn’t use the stack (see rule
> 115). Rather, the player simply puts the land onto the battlefield.
> Since the land doesn’t go on the stack, it is never a spell, and
> players can’t respond to it with instants or activated abilities.
>
> 305.2. A player can normally play one land during his or her turn; however, continuous effects may increase this number.
>
> 305.2a To determine whether a player can play a land, compare the number of lands the player can play this turn with the number of lands
> he or she has already played this turn (including lands played as
> special actions and lands played during the resolution of spells and
> abilities). If the number of lands the player can play is greater, the
> play is legal.
>
> 305.2b A player can’t play a land, for any reason, if the number of lands the player can play this turn is equal to or less than the
> number of lands he or she has already played this turn. Ignore any
> part of an effect that instructs a player to do so.
>
> 305.3. A player can’t play a land, for any reason, if it isn’t his or her turn. Ignore any part of an effect that instructs a player to do
> so.
>
> 305.4. Effects may also allow players to “put” lands onto the battlefield. This isn’t the same as “playing a land” and doesn’t count
> as a land played during the current turn.

So yes, you can choose a land and you can **play** it.
But it counts for the maximum amount of land played during a turn, because it's say that you **play** the land and not **put it on the battlefield**

Comment: Ah ok, I actually didn't know that it would count for my land for the turn, thanks!